Lowercaseing a macro
I have text that I want to link to a dictionary. In the MWE, I show a small sample. It works on lowercase examples (three words as an example) but not on text with an initial capital letter. While I can process the variable length lists, I can not contrive an expansion of the macro \word. So the first question would be the macro expansion in context, while the second question would be how do I lowercase it? A naive approach using \lowercase on \word fails, as does creating a macro returning \lowercase{#1}. While writing this up, I noticed the word 'Bhalloch,' with the comma, which shows an additional need to get my hands on the contents of \word.
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\hbadness=99999
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\setsepchar{ }% parsing-separator = space
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }{%
    \readlist\phrase{#1}%
    \foreachitem\word\in\phrase{\hyperlink{\word}{\word}~}%
}

\begin{document}
    \test{Dùisg Mo Rùn}\\
    Wake Up My Love\\

    \test{Dùisg mo rùn is tuiginn leam}\\
    \test{Tog do shùilean fada bhuat}\\
    \test{Air trèan a Bhalloch, cuir am baile ri d' chùl}\\
    \test{Is leanaidh sinn a' gheallaich}.\\
    \vdots\\
    \test{dùisg mo rùn}\\
\pagebreak
\newline
\hypertarget{dùisg}{dùisg}, *DOO-shk*, verb, "wake up" or "awaken"\newline
\hypertarget{mo}{mo}, *mo*, pronoun, "my"\newline
\hypertarget{rùn}{rùn}, *ROON*, noun, "secret" or "intention"

\end{document}


never use \lowercase, I am not sure I understand the question but \MakeLowercase{\word} or \MakeTitlecase{\word} are probably what you need

Gaeleg ... :-) It isn't clear what the intended result is here. most of the words in your test phrases don't have corresponding targets to link to and, while you mention the complications introduced by punctuation, it isn't clear what you want to do about it. you say it shows you need to 'get your hands on the contents of \word' but, of course, \word includes the comma, apostrophe or whatever. I don't know any gaelic, but if it uses constructions such as mae'r baban yn cysgu, then you also have problems there. better gaelic, though. at least it doesn't have mutations. :)

Instead of listofitems and its \readlist and \foreachitem I'd use \NewDocumentCommand \test { >{\SplitList{ }}m }{\ProcessList{#1}\testAux}, then \testAux gets each word as a normal argument in #1 and you don't need to care about expanding \word.

Thanks all. \lowercase is just the first that occurred to me. @cfr, There is A lack of other words in the dictionary simply because I felt the MWE illustrated the problem. And yes, there is embedded punctuation as well. Assuming I had access, I only have to deal with a limited set of trailing characters. @Skillmon, I will attempt a new version shortly based on your advice.

you can also combine argument processors like \SplitList, so you could further split at, say apostrophes, if you wished. or you could do this after getting \word.

In my initial testing, \hyperlink{\MakeLowercase{#1}}{#1}~ correctly does the linking, but not the case changing.  I assume (shouldn't do that) the doc(s) on \SplitList will show me what you mean @cfr?

If just doing \hypertarget{<destination/name of target area at the time of displaying pdf-file>}{<textual phrase determining target area at the time of typesetting/creating pdf-file>}, without \Hy@raisedlink, then, when clicking a link to the target, with many pdf-viewers scrolling is done so that the left of the baseline of the first line of the textual phrase is scrolled to the top-left edge of the window where the pdf file is displayed.

In consequence scrolling is so that you see only the descenders of the glyphs that make the first line of the textual phrase. In case the first line of the textual phrase does not have glyphes with descenders, you don't see anything of the first line of the textual phrase at all. Instead of \hypertarget{dùisg}{dùisg} consider doing s.th. like \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{dùisg}{}}dùisg.  This way the target for hyperlinking is not an area but is an anchor, i.e., a single point at the left of the begin of the textual phrase and a bit atop the baseline of the first line of the textual phrase.

Scrolling to this point/anchor moves this point/anchor to the top-left corner of the window where the pdf-file is displayed. As the baseline is below that point/anchor, you also see the ascenders of the glyphes of the first line of the textual phrase.

@UlrichDiez if I use \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}{#1} I get an undefined control sequence error. Which puzzles me since it is clearly defined in the hyperref package!

@hsmyers The name of \Hy@raisedlink contains @ which usually is of category 12(other) while at the time of tokenization only characters of category 11(letter) are taken for components of the names of control word tokens. So outside .sty/.cls-files and .aux-files where @ is given category 11(letter) you need \makeatletter...\makeatother. Or in the preamble do \begingroup\makeatletter\@firstofone{\endgroup\AtBeginDocument{\@ifdefinable\MyRaisedLink{\let\MyRaisedLink=\Hy@raisedlink}}}% and in the document-environment instead of \Hy@raisedlink use \MyRaisedLink.

@hsmyers Alternatively, in the document-environment, where @ is not of category 11(letter), use \csname Hy@raisedlink\endcsname or - with recent LaTeX - \UseName{Hy@raisedlink} for having TeX construct the control word token \Hy@raisedlink from character tokens in the stage of expansion rather than have TeX create it in the stage of tokenization.

@hsmyers You don't need {...} with the second #1 as that is not an argument of \Hy@raisedlink: \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}#1. There not being a breakpoint between \Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}} and the first thing of subsequent #1 is sufficient.

@UlrichDiez I give it another go. As for the @ sign, the macro is inside of the LaTeX3 guards which takes care of the cat problem I think?

@hsmyers LaTeX 3 does not take care of \makeatletter/\makeatother. When using control word tokens with @ in their names, you need to ensure that @ is of category 11(letter) even between \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff. Afaik that's because when LaTeX3 development begun, expl3 was not intended to be added to LaTeX 2e but LaTeX3 was intended to replace LaTeX 2e whereby the \makeatletter/\makeatother-thingie was intended to be abolished. With \ExplSyntaxOn you can do \use:c{Hy@raisedlink} for having TeX construct the token \Hy@raisedlink in the stage of expansion.

@UlrichDiez, thank you for the heads-up. I'll change my code accordingly and see what happens.

Use expl3 and not listofitems. You can apply \str_casefold:n that's exactly the tool you need.
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {~} {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \hyperlink{\str_casefold:n{##1}}{##1}~
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\hyper}{m}
 {
  \hypertarget{\str_casefold:n{#1}}{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{Dùisg Mo Rùn}\\
Wake Up My Love\\

\test{Dùisg mo rùn is tuiginn leam}\\
\test{Tog do shùilean fada bhuat}\\
\test{Air trèan a Bhalloch, cuir am baile ri d' chùl}\\
\test{Is leanaidh sinn a' gheallaich}.\\
\vdots\\
\test{dùisg mo rùn}\\

\vspace{10cm}

\hyper{dùisg}, *DOO-shk*, verb, “wake up” or “awaken”\newline
\hyper{mo}, *mo*, pronoun, “my”\newline
\hyper{rùn}, *ROON*, noun, “secret” or “intention”

\end{document}


What about punctuation? It's more complex, but doable.
Instead of just taking each word (including punctuation), we separate off the stringified version and the textual version. Then the last character in the stringified version is checked against a list of punctuation characters; if it's found, then the hyperlink will be labeled by the string without the last character, so, as in the example, the target can use “Bhalloch”.
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {~} {#1}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \__myers_hyper:n
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\hyper}{m}
 {
  \hypertarget{\str_casefold:n{#1}}{#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__myers_hyper:n
 {
  \__myers_hyper_a:en { \str_casefold:n {#1} } {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__myers_hyper_a:nn
 {
  \exp_args:Nne \str_if_in:nnTF { .,;:!? } { \str_item:nn {#1} {-1} }
   {
    \__myers_hyper_b:en { \str_range:nnn {#1} {1} {-2} } {#2}
   }
   {
    \__myers_hyper_b:nn {#1} {#2}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__myers_hyper_a:nn {e}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__myers_hyper_b:nn
 {
  \hyperlink{\str_casefold:n{#1}}{#2}~
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__myers_hyper_b:nn {e}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{Dùisg Mo Rùn}\\
Wake Up My Love\\

\test{Dùisg mo rùn is tuiginn leam}\\
\test{Tog do shùilean fada bhuat}\\
\test{Air trèan a Bhalloch, cuir am baile ri d' chùl}\\
\test{Is leanaidh sinn a' gheallaich}.\\
\vdots\\
\test{dùisg mo rùn}\\

\vspace{3cm}

\hyper{dùisg}, *DOO-shk*, verb, “wake up” or “awaken”

\hyper{mo}, *mo*, pronoun, “my”

\hyper{rùn}, *ROON*, noun, “secret” or “intention”

\hyper{Bhalloch}, *???*, something

\end{document}



As usual, your answer is spot on! That said, do you have suggestions concerning punctuation, i.e., the comma and the period?

@hsmyers That's much more problematic.

Thought it might be since they need to be stripped in one case and restored in the other!

+1 but I think \str_foldcase:n is deprecated for \str_casefold:n

@mbert The difference being?

@hsmyers No difference, the name was simply changed to \str_casefold:n. So the example will error if you turn debugging on, but I doubt the latex team will ever remove the deprecated commands

@mbert Yes, I went with the old name.

@hsmyers I added something taking care of punctuation.

You certainly did that @egreg. Further is seems to scroll to the correct place! My thanks again. I will stare at the LaTeX3 until either my eyes bleed or I reach understanding!

If you are using an old non-Unicode TeX engine (pdftex), then \lowercase{Dùisg} doesn't work because there are characters unrecognized by non Unicode \lowercase TeX primitive. But It works in Unicode TeX engine LuaTeX. If your example is processed by LuaLaTeX then there is no problem. I recommend using Unicode TeX engines only. Today, there is no reason for using the old non-Unicode TeX engine.

I use XeLaTeX only. I've no experience with LuaTex.
